# Comparing Dataframes and taking their difference

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a complicated problem but I will try to explain it with much detail. I have the following 2 dataframes and I need to do a little comparison and put the difference inside another dataframe. The criteria for the comparison can be seen below.

```
initial = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ['123', '456', '789', '000','231'],
                     'ProductName': ['Apple','Pear','Mango','Banana','Jackfruit'],
                     'DiscountedPrice': ['0.99', '1.00', '1.50', '2.10','2.35'],
                      'DiscountStartDate': ['30/01/2020', '21/06/2020', '01/01/2020', '10/11/2020','05/05/2020'],
                      'DiscountEndDate': ['25/03/2020', '30/07/2020', '30/01/2020', '12/12/2020','06/06/2020']}) 

updated = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ['123', '456', '789', '000','231'],
                     'ProductName': ['Apple','Pear','Mango','Banana','Jackfruit'],
                     'DiscountedPrice': ['0.53', '1.00', '0.99', '2.00','2.35'],
                      'DiscountStartDate': ['30/01/2020', '21/06/2020', '15/01/2020', '30/11/2020','09/10/2020'],
                      'DiscountEndDate': ['25/03/2020', '30/07/2020', '30/01/2020', '12/12/2020','31/10/2020']})
```

The comparison criteria are;

(1) If the discounted price & start/end date on both dataframes  are the same, ignore.

(2) If the discounted price is the same but start/end date is different, I would need to take both entries into my 'changes' dataframe

(3) If the discounted price for both dataframes are different but start & end dates are the same, I would need to take the DiscountedPrice & start/end dates from the 'updated' dataframe into my 'changes' dataframe

(4) If the discounted price are different and their start/end dates are overlapping somehow, I would need to adjust the end date of the initial to be -1 of the updated's start date and take both entries into my 'changes' dataframe

Basically, the 'changes' dataframe output would have to look like the table below.

| ProductID | ProductName | DiscountedPrice | DiscountStartDate | DiscountEndDate |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Apple | 0.53 | 30/01/2020 | 25/03/2020 |
| 789 | Mango | 1.50 | 01/01/2020 | 14/01/2020 |
| 789 | Mango | 0.99 | 15/01/2020 | 30/01/2020 |
| 000 | Banana | 2.10 | 10/11/2020 | 29/11/2020 |
| 000 | Banana | 2.00 | 30/11/2020 | 12/12/2020 |
| 231 | Jackfruit | 2.35 | 05/05/2020 | 06/06/2020 |
| 231 | Jackfruit | 2.35 | 09/10/2020 | 31/10/2020 |

Can someone help me with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merge the two DataFrames so the logic can be applied to identify all four cases.  With cases identified,  date can be modified and results concatenated back together.  Have added which case it is to **changes** dataframe for sake of transparency.

```
initial = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ['123', '456', '789', '000','231'],
                     'ProductName': ['Apple','Pear','Mango','Banana','Jackfruit'],
                     'DiscountedPrice': ['0.99', '1.00', '1.50', '2.10','2.35'],
                      'DiscountStartDate': ['30/01/2020', '21/06/2020', '01/01/2020', '10/11/2020','05/05/2020'],
                      'DiscountEndDate': ['25/03/2020', '30/07/2020', '30/01/2020', '12/12/2020','06/06/2020']}) 

updated = pd.DataFrame({'ProductID': ['123', '456', '789', '000','231'],
                     'ProductName': ['Apple','Pear','Mango','Banana','Jackfruit'],
                     'DiscountedPrice': ['0.53', '1.00', '0.99', '2.00','2.35'],
                      'DiscountStartDate': ['30/01/2020', '21/06/2020', '15/01/2020', '30/11/2020','09/10/2020'],
                      'DiscountEndDate': ['25/03/2020', '30/07/2020', '30/01/2020', '12/12/2020','31/10/2020']}) 
 
initial["DiscountStartDate"] = pd.to_datetime(initial["DiscountStartDate"])
initial["DiscountEndDate"] = pd.to_datetime(initial["DiscountEndDate"])
updated["DiscountStartDate"] = pd.to_datetime(updated["DiscountStartDate"])
updated["DiscountEndDate"] = pd.to_datetime(updated["DiscountEndDate"])


# merge two dataframes so that values can be identified
dfcat = (initial
 .merge(updated, on=["ProductID"], suffixes=("_i","_u"))
# cascading logic to mark which each of the 4 cases
 .assign(cat=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["DiscountStartDate_i"].eq(dfa["DiscountStartDate_u"])
                                  &dfa["DiscountEndDate_i"].eq(dfa["DiscountEndDate_u"])
                                  &dfa["DiscountedPrice_i"].eq(dfa["DiscountedPrice_u"])
                                  ,"case1",
                                  # no need to check dates different - done in case1
                                  np.where(dfa["DiscountedPrice_i"].eq(dfa["DiscountedPrice_u"])
                                           ,"case2",
                                np.where(dfa["DiscountEndDate_i"].eq(dfa["DiscountEndDate_u"])
                                  &dfa["DiscountStartDate_i"].eq(dfa["DiscountStartDate_u"])

                                  ,"case3", "case4")))
# case 4, modify EndDate
        ,DiscountEndDate_i=lambda dfa: np.where(dfa["cat"].eq("case4"),
                                                dfa["DiscountStartDate_u"] - pd.to_timedelta(1,unit="d"),
                                                dfa["DiscountEndDate_i"])

 
))

# utility to filter data and rename columns for each of the cases
def chngrows(df, case, ind):
    return (df
            .query(f"cat.isin(['{case}'])")
            .loc[:,["ProductID"]+[c for c in dfcat.columns if ind in c]]
            .rename(columns={c:c.replace(ind,"") for c in dfcat.columns if ind in c})
            .assign(cat=f"{case}{ind}")
           )


changes = pd.concat([
    chngrows(dfcat, "case2", "_i"),
    chngrows(dfcat, "case2", "_u"),
    chngrows(dfcat, "case3", "_u"),
    chngrows(dfcat, "case4", "_i"),
    chngrows(dfcat, "case4", "_u"),
]).sort_values(["ProductID","cat"])
```

### output

```
ProductID ProductName DiscountedPrice DiscountStartDate DiscountEndDate      cat
      000      Banana            2.10        2020-10-11      2020-11-29  case4_i
      000      Banana            2.00        2020-11-30      2020-12-12  case4_u
      123       Apple            0.53        2020-01-30      2020-03-25  case3_u
      231   Jackfruit            2.35        2020-05-05      2020-06-06  case2_i
      231   Jackfruit            2.35        2020-09-10      2020-10-31  case2_u
      789       Mango            1.50        2020-01-01      2020-01-14  case4_i
      789       Mango            0.99        2020-01-15      2020-01-30  case4_u
```